# Can I use Firebase for sending SMS to users without using Twilio?

Tags: firebase, twilio

I used to use Firebase + Twilio to send SMS to any devices,
but I'm not sure that I can send SMS by using Firebase only or not?

Does Firebase have an API for sending SMS?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can send SMS Verification using Firebase and **you cannot send ordinary SMS** through Firebase. You can send using Twilio instead.

Even for SMS verification, you have to wait until they release the API docs for SMS verification through Android.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: The question specifically states not wanting to use Twilio. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Also, let's not add Firebase Phone Auth to this particular question, as it would shoot a users in doing something with that Auth SMS... and in all that RnD there's a great chance that the poor guys PhoneAuth service would get throttled!

Answer (score 20):

There is no built-in API for sending SMS through Firebase. You will have to use a third-party service (such as you're currently doing with Twilio) to send SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

Till Now there is no way to send sms with firebase only.
what is now available is, can send sms for phone no authentication.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

I think firebase will release this feature soon , because it is becoming a common need for android deveopers.

Comment: This just repeats existing answers. Please reserve answers for content that hasn't already been given by other answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Only the OTP ( SMS ) verification in firebase , you cannot send normal sms  ,for that you need to use third party libraries

Comment: This just repeats existing answers. Please reserve answers for content that hasn't already been given by other answerers.