# How to send sms via firebase curl

Tags: android, firebase, twilio

I have an **app** which use **authorization** via **twilio**. And i wanted to use **firebase** **instead** **twilio**, but without a big change of code.

The auth now works as:

android -> server -> twilio server (sms was send)

server sends an http request to twilio server, kinda like this

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACaa3cd370b...a5312c404ce/Messages.json \
  --data-urlencode "Body=This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?" \
  --data-urlencode "From=+1938...6285" \
  --data-urlencode "To=+99670...4137" \
  -u ACaa3cd370b...a5312c404ce:d5027e7d53b6...d9ac4ab0e89
```

and what i want to do, is to change http request to firebase instead. But actually i don't know is it possible or not. I don't have much experience.

Firebase works with cloud server, i mean the request goes right to the firebase server, which means i can create a connection with android studio, and check the verification inside the app.

Am i facing a dead end, or is there any solution?

Wasn't able to find anything, "firebase sms curl send" shows only push notification results

There also was one [example](https://medium.com/@shangyilim/verifying-phone-numbers-with-firebase-phone-authentication-on-your-backend-for-free-7a9bef326d02)

```
curl -X POST \
      'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?key=api_key' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      -d '{
     "phoneNumber": "phone_number_to_verify",
     "recaptchaToken": "generated_recaptcha_token"
    }'
```

But I didn't received any sms and also there is no information about usage, or maybe i am phrasing not quite right, please advice

Comment: You can remove your answer and then remove the question to revert back a rating (-2).

Answer (score 0):

How sadly is it was, but there is no solution. You can't send sms via firebase, only use their android-studio-firebase-hardcode-architecture .

Here found a topic "[Can I use Firebase for sending SMS to users without using Twilio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361815/can-i-use-firebase-for-sending-sms-to-users-without-using-twilio)" and the answer is NO